# Defining an alias for XML element in XSD Schema

Tags: xml, xsd, alias

Is there XSD language support or tricks (e.g. via the preprocessor) for defining an alias for an XML element? I would like to alias all the elements in my schema in order to create an option for a more cryptic but network bandwidth-efficient version of our XML documents.

For example, I would like to define a name such as `IRQ` to be an alias for the element `InterruptRequest` etc.

```
<xs:element name="InterruptRequest" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="level" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So that the following two declarations are equivalent to each other

```
<!-- Human readable but bandwidth inefficient -->
<InterruptRequest level="22" /> 

<!-- Cryptic, but comparatively bandwidth efficient -->
<IRQ level="22" />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't define two element names to be synonymous, but you can define one as substitutable for the other by means of a substitution group. They will still appear differently to your application, but the validation process will permit one of them to be used everywhere that the content model permits the other.

```
<element name="a">...

<element name="b" substitutionGroup="a">...
```

Comment: substitutionGroup's are great. However, in my case the elements appear in a choice element. So I guess I could just repeat both names in the choice 'list'.

Comment: Does it work for elements imported from another schema?

Comment: Please don't ask supplementary questions in the form of comments, especially when the original question is 10 years old. Start a new thread.