# XML attribute alias

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

Is there a way to declare an alias for element attributes? For example I've got an element `<Item>` with two boolean attributes `fooAttribute` and `barAttribute`, with aliases `foo` and `bar` such that any of the following is valid:

```
<Item foo="true" bar="false" />
<Item foo="true" barAttribute="false" />
<Item fooAttribute="true" bar="false" />
<Item fooAttribute="true" barAttribute="false" />
```

Comment: Is an alias desirable? Doesn't that make parsing out the data harder work.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460560/defining-an-alias-for-xml-element-in-xsd-schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is not in XSD 1.0. You could combine XSD 1.0 with another schema language (RelaxNG or Schematron), if you want.

In XSD 1.1 you could define both variants of the attribute, point to the same simple type for some sort of reuse, and then define assertions to make them mutually exclusive.